# Pronunciation of Detritus

Tags: pronunciation

I had thought that *detritus* would be pronounced like *detriment*, but apparently not.

Why not?

Is there something in the etymology?

Are there any other words of English origin written "-trit-" pronounced "trai"?

Comment: You could say it either way, but I have heard the conventional pronunciation is like "deh-try-tus." It is a long vowel sound for the "i," nothing too farfetched.  Think "Triton" "trident" or "triage"

Comment: What do common online dictionaries give as its pronunciation?

Comment: @Carly 'triage' is surely from French and pronounced as in the second recording here  https://www.howtopronounce.com/triage/  Sorry I can't write IPA, but the first syllable is 'tree' not 'try'.

Comment: Contrite/contrition

Comment: Merriam Webster: de·​tri·​tus | \ di-ˈtrī-təs  \
plural detritus\ di-​ˈtrī-​təs  , -​ˈtrī-​ˌtüs

Comment: I don’t think there are any words in English, including _detritus_, where _-trit-_ is pronounced /traɪ/.

Answer (score 4):

The identity of a preceding consonant is rarely relevant to the pronunciation of a vowel letter in English, so I don't think it's very helpful to look for other words spelled with *-trit-.* That said, Carly and Mynamite's comments have pointed out other examples, such as *Triton* and *contrite;* I'll add *gastritis, nitrite, attrited.*

#### Many pronunciations are possible in principle for words with this spelling pattern

If you're trying to examine patterns to the pronunciation and spelling of English words, it's more fruitful to look at the letters *after* a vowel: in particular, the number of consonant letters directly after it, and the number of syllables until the end of the word.

In general, when a word ends in the spelling pattern VCVC (where V represents a single "vowel letter", i.e. one of {a e i o u y}, and C represents a single "consonant letter") the first V might be pronounced with a "long vowel" sound if it is in a stressed syllable.

So, when the vowel in the second-to-last syllable is I (as in *detr**i**tus*), it might be pronounced as a "long i" sound /aɪ/. Other examples of a "long i" sound in this context: *hor**i**zon, arthr**i**tis, div**i**sor, rev**i**val, suic**i**dal, cl**i**max, **i**tem, t**i**tan, ch**i**tin, cr**i**sis*.

I said "might" because it's also possible for a vowel to be "short" and stressed in this context, as in *exh**i**bit, expl**i**cit, l**i**nen, m**i**mic.*

And in words of more than two syllables ending in the spelling pattern VCVC, it's very common for the second-to-last syllable to be unstressed (as in *or**i**gin, off**i**cer, crim**i**nal,* and your own example of *detr**i**ment*).

#### Why words with the same spelling pattern have different pronunciations

You brought up etymology. This is a common influence on a word's pronunciation.

It's likely that the pronunciation of *detritus* with stress on the second-to-last syllable is derived from the pronunciation of the Latin word *detritus* (which had a long vowel in the first and second syllable: *dētrītus*), which is stressed on the second-to-last syllable.

English words that have the exact same form as their Latin source are often stressed in the same position (but not always: some words such as *abdomen* and *acumen*—once commonly pronounced with stress on the second-to-last syllable, as in Latin—are now widely pronounced with stress on the third-to-last syllable).

But English words that end differently from their Latin source are often stressed in a different position. The word *detriment* ultimately comes from the Latin word *detrimentum,* pronounced *dētrīˈmentum* (with stress on the second-to-last syllable). But in English, *detriment* is stressed on the first syllable rather than on the last.